# Is there a way to get F#'s constructor-parameters-are-automatically-immutable-private-members feature in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor, f#, immutability

In F#, the constructor parameters are automatically saved as immutable fields in the class without having to write the declaration of the field or the copying of the constructor parameter to the field in the constructor.

Is there any way to mimic this functionality in C#?  Is there a reason why a future version of C# couldn't have this feature (i.e. is there some fundamental limitation of the existing language that conflicts with this feature)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C# equivalent will be [records](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39). These are currently earmarked for C# 8, but there's no guarantees (especially as they were proposed for C# 6 & 7 too and were delayed in both cases).

Comment: I think a closer feature would be [Primary Constructors](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/08/14/c-6-0-features-part-ii-primary-constructors.aspx).

Comment: @ScottWhitlock, my understanding is that records will be classes and structs with primary constructor syntax, along with some lowering features to add eg equality functionality and the like. So I think the two are now combined into the one feature. I could be wrong though.